# MySQL order by syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Ive just seen the following syntax : `select * from table order by column = "b" desc`
I guess that the rows with value "b" will come first but i am not sure.
What does the query mean and how sorting works in this case.

Ive searched on google about it but ... no success.

Comment: if you want to know how sorting will be, just add the order by part in select part `SELECT *, column = "3" sort FROM table ORDER BY column = "3" DESC` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b07c5/2/0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, you are not limited by sorting on values of existing columns: you can specify complex expressions inside your `order by` clause. This query sorts by the value of a boolean expression: the expression will be true for the rows where `column = 'b'`, and `false` in all other rows. As the result, rows with column = 'b' will come first, because the `order by` clause specifies descending order, and in SQL, `true` is represented as 1, and `false` is 0.

Comment: oh thanks :) but what about the rest that return false...what would their order be?

Comment: @alexander `false` is "less than" `true`; all rows with `b` will be ahead of any row without `b`, but other than that the order of rows would remain unchanged. Since there is no "tie breaker", the rows inside the two groups (i.e. with and without `'b'`) will remain unordered.

Comment: In SQL, true is represented a 1, false is 0.

Comment: You would have to do something like `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column = "b" DESC, column DESC` to sort the rest of the rows in `column`.